# WP7 XNA + SilverLight + Touch = Wrong Coordinates?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, xna, touch

I'm using the mixed XNA/SL programming model where the Silverlight content is rendered by UIElementRenderer.  However, it appears that there is a 40 pixel offset between the screen coordinates reported by touch (GestureSample) and the actual coordinates where the contents of the page are rendering.

It appears to be space reserved for the SystemTray in Silverlight apps.

My question is: is there an API I can call to dynamically return this offset so I don't have to hard-code it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually think there is any such offset. Since the `GestureSample` has accurate screen coordinates, your problem is probably with drawing the silverlight UI. Make sure that you don't have any view/projection transforms active on your `SpriteBatch` when you draw the uiRenderer texture.

If you were using a transform to draw your game scene, you might just want to end that `SpriteBatch` and start up a new one for screen UI.